# Уточняющие члены предложении

Tags: запятая

Почему нет уточняющего члена предложения в этом предложении:

*"В передней у двери стоит деревянный сундучок, где Есенин хранил книги любимых русских поэтов и писателей: Пушкина, Лермонтова, Кольцова, Гоголя".*

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться и как уточняющие, и не как уточняющие. Видимо, автор не счёл сделать уточняющие паузы. "В спальне на ковре над кроватью висело ружьё" - такой же пример. Можно ставить, можно не ставить запятые. Видимо, здесь уточнять не приходится, и так понятно.

"В передней у двери стоит деревянный сундучок, где Есенин хранил книги ...". Вероятно, невелика передняя, чтобы уточнять, где именно там сундучок, взгляд его сразу выхватывает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!